# microsoft translate giving invalid language error

Tags: microsoft-translator

Anyone have luck with the microsoft translator api. I feel like I followed everything, and have used the same url in the example from the actual site, but I am getting an error.

this is the url I am using for a get req:
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate?text="hi"&from="en"&to="es"

this is the response I am getting back:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Argument Exception</h1>
        <p>Method: Translate()</p>
        <p>Parameter: from</p>
        <p>Message: 'from' must be a valid language&#xD;
Parameter name: from</p>
        <code></code>
        <p>message id=1230.V2_Rest.Translate.5368F73A</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Pretty sure english and spanish are both actual languages lol.

Comment: Oh and to add to this if I change the ? to & after Translate the call takes me to microsofts website haha

Answer (score 0):

:| figured it out. Cant have quotes around the language haha. Incase anyone runs in to this issue.